# Can CKFinder return a 'virtual' path?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckfinder

My website stores images in the App_Data folder (~/App_Data/content/images) and serves them via a MVC 'images' controller (for dynamic resizing etc..).

CKFinder can browse, select & upload images by setting the BaseUrl to the above folder, but I'd like it to return a different base url to CKEditor than the one it is actually browsing - e.g. '/images/test.jpg' instead of '/App_Data/content.images/test.jpg'.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found out they were discussing about some similar issue [here](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=7115&sid=ffc79b0f3766c76aaa0b9d29f83e345a&start=10). It might help you.